# Clarification needed for the proof of $\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1 \cap U_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler:

> **Theorem 2.18**:
>
> If $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space,
>   then:
>
> $\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim(U_1)+\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1 \cap U_2)$

PROOF (in short):

Let $(u_1,u_2,...)$ be a basis of $U_1\cap U_2$. This can be extended to a basis $(u_1,u_2,...,u_m,v_1,v_2,...,v_j)$ of $U_1$. Also, it can be extended to a basis $(u_1,u_2,...,u_m,w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$ of $U_2$.

Clearly $\text{span}(u_1,...,u_m,v_1,...,v_j,w_1,...,w_k)$ is $U_1 + U_2$. To show that this list is a basis of $U_1+U_2$ we just need to show that it is linearly independent.

To prove this, suppose:

$a_1u_1+...+a_mu_m+b_1v_1+...+b_jv_j+c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k=0$

$\implies c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k = -(b_1v_1+...+b_jv_j+a_1u_1+...+a_mu_m)$

This shows that $c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k \in U_1$ which is evident looking at the right hand side of the previous equality.

However, after this the book says: "All the $w$'s are in $U_2$, so this implies that $c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k \in U_1\cap U_2$"

I am having trouble understanding this statement. We had to extend $(u_1,u_2,...)$ to $(u_1,u_2,...,u_m,w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$ in order to cover the region of whole region of $U_2$ (i.e. include the regions outside of $U_1\cap U_2$ in $U_2$). So it should mean that $(w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$ is basis of $U_2-U_1\cap U_2$. But they claim that $c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k \in U_1\cap U_2$ which seems contradictory!

Am I making any conceptual error?

Comment: Do you agree that the $w$'s are in $U_2$?  Since $U_2$ is a vector space, then any linear combination of the $w$'s must also be in $U_2$. [Note that the statement "$c_1w_1 + ... + c_kw_k \in U_1 \cap U_2$ just means that $c_1w_1 + ... + c_kw_k \in U_1$ and $c_1w_1 + ... + c_kw_k \in U_2$].

Comment: @Michael My problem is that $(w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$ was initially introduced to span the region *outside of* $U_1\cap U_2$ but in $U_2$ (as $(u_1,u_2,..,u_m)$ could only span $U_1\cap U_2$ and not the whole $U_2$). So how can a linear combination of $(w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$ be an element of $U_1\cap U_2$ ?

Comment: I think Bernard gave an answer to that.  This is kind of like trying to "work towards a contradiction" in proof by contradiction, then getting confused at the end because we ended up with something contradictory and forgetting that is what we _wanted_ to do.  Here, we are not working towards a contradiction, just working towrads showing the big sum of vectors is really just 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conceptual error is this:

> ...it should mean that $(w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$ is basis of $U_2-U_1\cap U_2$.

This is meaningless, as $U_2-U_1\cap U_2$ is *not* a subspace. 
$(w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$ is a basis of a complement of $U_1\cap U_2$ w.r.t. $U_2$, that's all. A *complement* of a subspace is not the *difference set*.

Comment: If $(w_1,w_2,...,w_k)$ is a basis of the **complement** of the subspace $U_1\cap U_2$ w.r.t $U_2$, then how can it's linear combination $c_1w_1+...+c_kw_k $ be an element of $U_1\cap U_2$ ? It would be helpful if you address this concern a bit...

Comment: Precisely, it can't, unless it's $0$.

Comment: The complement subspace is a subspace $V\subset U_2$ such that $U_2=U_1\cap U_2\oplus V$. For instance , in $\mathbf R^2$, a complement of the $x$-axis is  any vector line with basis a vector not collinear with the vector $(1,0)$, whereas the difference set is the set of all vectors $(x,y)$ such that $y\ne 0$ – this is not even a vector (sub)space.

Answer (score 2):

Since $w_1,\ldots,w_k\in U_2$, $c_1w_1+\cdots c_kw_k\in U_2$. But you also know that $c_1w_1+\cdots c_kw_k\in U_1$. Therefore, $c_1w_1+\cdots c_kw_k\in U_1\cap U_2$.

There is a conceptual problem in what you wrote. You wrote that $\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\}$ is a basis of $U_2\setminus U_1\cap U_2$. How can that be? $U_2\setminus U_1\cap U_2$ is not a vector space.

Comment: I'm not sure why you got a downvote.  I gave you +1.

Comment: @Michael I also don't understand it.

Comment: It seems to have corrected itself.  Likely a mis-hit.

Comment: @Michael Right; it was corrected.